# cURL error "Could not resolve host" when pointing towards local drive with XAMPP

Tags: php, curl, xampp

In a certain API script, I want to run an AJAX file from within a PHP file, to post the vars to the AJAX file. I'd prefer not having to include the AJAX file for a nicer solution, since it's made to receive post vars. When I run the cURL locally using XAMPP I get the following error:

```
Curl error: Could not resolve host: C
```

Is semicolon an invalid char for cURL? How can I run cURL locally, pointing towards a file on the same server?

```
$isLocal = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'localhost') !== false);

if ($isLocal) {
    $documentRootWildcard = 'C:/_foretag/TourTask/Internet/Hemsidor/example.com';
} else {
    $documentRootWildcard = '/home/user5/_domains/example.com';
}

$curlUrl = $documentRootWildcard . '/ajax/bookings/save.php';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'ea5e7f894cde433a987d9b9979dfed5f:7ff527e78ace4e9291ee6f7a7d52141e');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json')
);

$curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);

if ($curlResponse === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else { //Successfully sent

}

curl_close($ch);
```

How can I solve this? Or is there a better solution? Thank you!

Comment: “run an AJAX file from within a PHP file”, that doesn’t really make sense, there’s no such thing as an AJAX file, there’s just JavaScript and HTML. Also, PHP code needs to be executed by the PHP process. This is usually handled by the web server itself, over HTTP, but you can manually invoke it using the PHP binary. For the latter, that’s not done using curl, however, you would be `proc_open` or `exec` land. That said, you are already in PHP, so you can just use the existing logic directly. I guess it isn’t clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: the curl url is the adress of the page when it is served. What you call document root should be replaced by something like `http://example.com` or `http://localhost` (the address of http server interpreting the php code). On your filesystem `save.php` it nothing more than a text file.

Comment: @Tuckbros ah I see, apparently I can't use server roots, only publically accesible files! I changed the first part to `https://localhost` as you said, and it worked like a charm! Thank you! 
ChrisHaas it's very possible I'm not using the correct terminology. With AJAX file I refer to the external PHP file that's normally called with HTTP request from within JavaScript (personally using AngularJS). I preferred not to use PHP `include()` to not have to edit the external PHP file that's being called for different situations, since it's already expecting posted vars.